# How can I mark with diff color item from enum that has no references

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

project is in `ReactJS` with `TypeScript` and work in `VS Code`
I have a big enum

```
export enum UtilMessages {
    UtilNr1 = 'Util Nr 1 is nr 1',
    UtilNr2 = 'Util Nr 2 is nr 2',
    ...
    UtilNr99999 = 'Util Nr 99999 is nr 99999'
}
```

somewere in code I have usage of enum items like

```
<Button>{UtilMessages.UtilNr1}</Button>
```

I want to remove all unused (items that has no references)

I can to remove all of them and one by one restore where compiller will show the usage error, but items are very much, and this process will consume a long time
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to remove them from `enum` declaration? You can just use `const enum`, in this way `enum` object will not be created at all

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes, enum contains many unused items

Comment: so you can try using `const enum`. you can check how it works in ts playground.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums . With const enum, you don't even need to remove unused properties. I'm not sure what the problem to remove unused properties